# How to run a sql script from an ant script

Tags: scripting, ant, sql-scripts

i need to rename a file in database using sql script. The sql script must be executed from an ant script.How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ant can call executables then you could call [the sqlcmd.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) - you can pass it a query as a string (using -Q) or you can tell it a file that contains your commands (using -i).